# RavendDB: Could not find transactional storage type

Tags: iis-7.5, ravendb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I cannot run Enmbedded RavenDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480168/i-cannot-run-enmbedded-ravendb)

I get the following error when trying to publish my application to my local IIS. It works great in Cassini and when I use IIS express but after doing Publish and pointing IIS to those files I get this message.

**Could not find transactional storage type: Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage, Raven.Storage.Esent**
**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details**: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find transactional storage type: Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage, Raven.Storage.Esent

Anyone have a clue?

**Stack Trace**:

[InvalidOperationException: Could not find transactional storage type: Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage, Raven.Storage.Esent]
   Raven.Database.Config.InMemoryRavenConfiguration.CreateTransactionalStorage(Action notifyAboutWork) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Config\InMemoryRavenConfiguration.cs:442
   Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase..ctor(InMemoryRavenConfiguration configuration) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:127
   Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddableDocumentStore.InitializeInternal() in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Embedded\EmbeddableDocumentStore.cs:134
   Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore.Initialize() in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\DocumentStore.cs:458
   Cashfluir.Bootstrapper.Startup() in C:\Users\Mikael\Documents\Programering\Projects\Cashfluir\Code\Cashfluir\Cashfluir\Bootstrapper.cs:21
   Cashfluir.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Users\Mikael\Documents\Programering\Projects\Cashfluir\Code\Cashfluir\Cashfluir.Web\Global.asax.cs:45

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not find transactional storage type: Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage, Raven.Storage.Esent]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +4051717
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +191
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +352
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +407
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +375

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not find transactional storage type: Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage, Raven.Storage.Esent]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11642112
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4865877